# Defining a non zero integer type in F#

Tags: types, f#, integer, subdomain

How I can define a non zero integer in F# that rise a compile time error when assigning zero value?

My question comes by watching this **Scott Wlaschin** video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8I19uA-wGY&t=960s in minute 16:00

I have found another answers to this question in SO but all refers to a dynamic checking(throwing exception at creation time) but this approach is not a big deal and can be done in any OO and not OO languages. What I'm looking is something like: `type NonZeroInteger = int except 0` or something like that.

Comment: Trying to figure out the scope of what you are trying to accomplish: should this type throw an exception if the result of the calculation is 0?

Comment: One approach is code contract + static verification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts. I suspect F* support this although I know very little F*.

Comment: @AlexanderM my intention is not to throw exceptions but failing in compile time as the video suggested.

Comment: @FuleSnabel the contracts usually are checked in runtime and fails by throwing exceptions. What I'm aiming is for a static checked type contraint.

Comment: F# is not Idris, you could accomplish this type of validation by building it into the constructor of the type of NonZeroInteger.

Comment: @hdkrus, sorry I did mean compilation error. I am not sure if it is possible now but looks like they are working towards hooking up Roslyn and F#. With that you might be able to get a compilation errors on direct assignment of zero. I am not sure but with current state of affairs the only way I could think of it would be possible to create a type in C# with Roslyn hooked in to check for 0 assignment and then use this type from F#. I know this is not what you really want and not 100% sure it would really work but worth of trying.

Comment: @hdkrus yes, code contracts are sometimes checked in runtime but there is also static verification that will try to prove that contract always hold.

Comment: @hdkrus If you are not afraid of a lot of work you could probably do something with F# compiler services to check that a NonZeroInteger can only be constructed with an integer that is proved to be not zero: https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/. A simple proof is `if n <> 0 then NonZeroInteger n` where as this should fail as there is no proof of non-zeroness: `NonZeroInteger n`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In F# there aren't really compile time contracts for what you want to do. The F# way to deal with this would be to have a type `NonZeroInteger` with a private constructor and a function that returns an `Option<NonZeroInteger>`. This will assure that you never have `Some(0)`.

What this does is basically forcing the developer who uses your code to account for the possibility that he might not have a `NonZeroInteger` after constructing one, when given the wrong integer value.

In your code you can then always safely assume that NonZeroIntegers are in fact non-zero.

```
open Option

module A =
    type NonZeroInteger =
        private | NonZeroInteger of int

        static member Create (v : int) : Option<NonZeroInteger> =
            if v = 0 then
                None
            else
                Some(NonZeroInteger(v))

        member this.Get : int =
            this |> fun (NonZeroInteger v) -> v

        member this.Print =
            this |> fun (NonZeroInteger v) -> printfn "%i" v


printfn "%A" (A.NonZeroInteger(0)) // error FS1093: The union cases or fields of the type 'NonZeroInteger' are not accessible from this code location

let wrong = A.NonZeroInteger.Create(0) // None
let right = A.NonZeroInteger.Create(-1) // Some

wrong |> Option.iter (fun x -> x.Print) // Doesn't print anything
right |> Option.iter (fun x -> x.Print) // Prints -1
```

The `private` constructor prevents anyone outside your module to construct a `NonZeroInteger` without going through your Create function.

This makes the code quite verbose and slow, but safe. So there's definitely a tradeoff here.

Comment: You basically answered my question in your first line. So F# doesn't has any  idiomatic construct for doing what I'm looking. I reviewed all solutions until now and all can be done in any no functional programming language, so why bother using F#? I mean I feel like the video's author gave a misleading advice just to create a biased point of view about functional programming.

Comment: That's true, you could do this in C# (maybe still a bit more verbose) and basically any other statically typed language. I find this is one of the things where F# needs an easier way to do it. I wouldn't write off F# completely because it has this one functional concept that isn't easy to express in it. There are plenty of other things where F# is great IMO. Piping, partial application, Hindley-Milner type-inference, match expressions, if expressions, strong typing, tuples,  partial struct copying, etc. make F# a great "functional-first" language. Is it perfect? No, but which language is?

Comment: I agree with you about that. However I'd prefer Scala because it integrates perfectly OO with functional programming, I mean within the same language I can use functional programming and OO concepts, despite having OO goodies I haven't seen in other languages like C# or Java. In the case of F# the advantage is that can be used in the .Net environment together with C#.

Comment: F# also combines functional and OO programming in one language, like I said you should look at the language as a whole instead of one missing feature. Scala is great, I'm not saying anything against it, but F# also has features (like the type inference, pipes and easy declaration of discriminated unions) that Scala doesn't have for functional. And F# is also a fully OO language.

Comment: @hdkrus I am currently learning F# and I share your sentiment. Sometimes Scott does drag C# through the mud by using older or deliberately verbose language constructs. However, many of the new features that I find he omits are actually lifted (I'm hilarious :D) from F#! You will find that it is useful that he has made these emissions as it really illustrates what the functional path should be.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are pretty idiomatic to F#, but here is a way to make it *impossible* to construct a zero value (at a slight inconvenience to the caller):

```
type Digit =
| One = 1
| Two = 2
| Three = 3
| Four = 4
| Five = 5
| Six = 6
| Seven = 7
| Eight = 8
| Nine = 9


type NonZero private(ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, ten_thousands) =    
    static let f (n : Digit) = int n

    member val num = f(ones) + 10 * tens + 100 * hundreds + 1000 * thousands + 10000 * ten_thousands

    new (ten_thousands, thousands, hundreds, tens, ones) = NonZero(ones, f tens, f hundreds, f thousands, f ten_thousands)
    new (thousands, hundreds, tens, ones) = NonZero(ones, f tens, f hundreds, f thousands, 0)
    new (hundreds, tens, ones) = NonZero(ones, f tens, f hundreds, 0, 0)
    new (tens, ones) = NonZero(ones, f tens, 0, 0, 0)
    new (ones) = NonZero(ones, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Here is how you would construct, say, the number 123:

```
let k = new NonZero(Digit.One, Digit.Two, Digit.Three)
```

And to retrieve the value:

```
let l = k.num //l is 123 : int
```

Hence, it is impossible to pass a zero value to a function with type `NonZero -> 'a`.

Comment: > let zero : Digit = enum 0;;


val zero : Digit = 0

Comment: @CurtNichols -- Good catch. If we were really serious, I suppose we could always replace the enum type with a class type, where `Digit` is abstract (and the cstor is private or internal) and each on of the variants is a subclass defined in the same module.

Comment: Your construct is nice but it's not what I'm asking for. This can be done in any OO language, I was looking an idiomatic resource in F# as suggested the Scott Wlaschin's video. But anyway thanks (+1) for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this directly, like with Scala's `require` for example.

Here's one way, which is somewhat DDD-ish:

```
type NonZeroInteger = private NonZeroInteger of int 
let createNZI i = 
  if i = 0 then
    Error "NonZeroInteger can't be Zero"
  else 
    Ok (NonZeroInteger i)
```

The constructor is private, so you will have to go through the createNZI function (you can switch the names if that is more natural). Than deal with the `Result` type. You can use Some/None instead if that is simpler. And finally unwrap the NonzeroInteger if necessary with pattern matching or an Active Pattern.

Comment: Scala's ***require*** works in runtime, so it's basically the same than throwing exceptions. Until now I don't know any language having this feature.

Comment: @hdkrus that's because most would approach it from the validation side. Reason being that if the 0 is passed in from the outside, like from a form, you will get a run-time exception anyway. However you may want to look at [Idris](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#first-class-types) that has dependent types, finite sets, ranges, etc.